# If $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

I'm currently studying for my Linear Algebra final tomorrow, and this question irked me:

**If $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, then**
(a) $A$ and $B$ must be similar matrices.
(b) $A$ and $B$ must have the same eigenvectors.
(c) $\text{det} A = \text{det} B$
(d) (a) and (b)
(e) all of the above

I ruled out (b), and thus (d), easily. It turns out the right answer was (c), but I came up with counterexamples that proved (c) wrong.

When the question says "same eigenvalues," I started by thinking about matrices with different algebraic multiplicities for the same eigenvalues.
Say $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ has eigenvalues 1, 1, 1, 2 and $4 \times 4$ matrix $B$ has eigenvalues 1, 1, 2, 2. They certainly have the same eigenvalues, but they're certainly not similar. And their determinants are, obviously, different.

Then I considered matrices with the same eigenvalues *and* the same algebraic multiplicites. But then, both (a) and (c) must be right, which isn't an option.

I guess I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of them is actually true, though changing the first line to

- If $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues with the same algebraic multiplicities

makes (c) true.  Even adding this does not make (a) true: for example,
$$A=\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&2\cr}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  B=\pmatrix{2&1\cr0&2\cr}$$
are not similar.  The matrix $B$ is an example of a Jordan matrix, don't know whether or not this is on your course.

Comment: Would (a) be true if A and B were forced to be diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: Yes, as then the diagonal forms of $A,B$ would be the same (up to order of diagonal elements).

Comment: Your modified statement is still false. If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, you need each of them to have $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume that the OP was considering matrices over $\Bbb C$.